# OOP - How to make a parent function perform some default functionality?

Tags: php, object-oriented-analysis

In PHP, I have an abstract class (parent) which is extended by the child class. I want the child class to implement a function of parent. And when I call the implemented function of child, a default functionality of parent should be invoked automatically. 
Is it possible?

For example, I want to create parent's log function every time a send function of child is invoked.

```
abstract class CommunicationService {
    // child classes must implement this
    abstract function send();
    abstract function receive();

    public function log($action) {
        echo 'Creating nice Log on = ' . $action;
    }
}

class ServiceA extends CommunicationService {
    public function send() {
        // Is it possible that the parent's logging functionality be invoked automatically by default?
        echo 'Send Message using Service A';
    }
    public function receive() {
        echo 'Receive Message using Service A';
    }
}

$serviceA = new ServiceA();
$serviceA->send(); // It should send message as well as create logs.
$serviceA->receive(); // It should just receive message and not log it.
```

Also, is it possible to perform some default action in parent and the rest of the functionality in child?

best regards.

Comment: This is a valid question. I wonder why it's been down voted? Care to share the reason please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any class which extends the parent needs its functions to explicitly call the parent `log()` function like this:

```
public function send() {
    // Is it possible that the parent's logging functionality be invoked automatically by default?
    parent::log( 'some text' ); // Tell the parent to log
    echo 'Send Message using Service A';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus
But I wonder if there's a way that we could force Child to call parent::log() here? Coz, I am afraid if someone forgets calling the log function in their implementation this would be a disaster.
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Waqas I am not sure if I fully understand your request. If a programmer is writing a child class which extends your parent class then how would you be able to preemptively know which child functions need to trigger a log?

Comment: @Waqas One idea is ff the child `send()` required a call to `parent::realSend( 'message' )` in order to send the message. So you could program `realSend()` to automatically call the log function. Aside from this, it's up to the programmer which is extending your class to know that `parent::log()` **must** be called.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address the second part of your question: "Is it possible to perform some default action in parent and the rest of the functionality in child?"  The answer is yes, and one way of doing so is to use a "design pattern" known as the [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

> The template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, *deferring some steps to subclasses.*

I've specifically done this with a ~60 line (not counting comments) PHP MVC micro-framework the source being here: https://github.com/dexygen/jackrabbitmvc/blob/master/barebones.lib.php

The template method is as follows:

```
static function sendResponse(IBareBonesController $controller) {
  $controller->setMto($controller->applyInputToModel());
  $controller->mto->applyModelToView();
}
```

The methods `$controller->setMto` and `mto->applyModelToView` get implemented elsewhere in the source code, but the child class has to implement `$controller->applyInputToModel` -- see the comments above the source.  Also see a write-up I did on [the inspiration for the framework](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KBHDS4EwyZyJAhcsNVCIOZ97HckSW4xSfDm7SfCscjQ/edit)

Comment: Thanks @George for pointing me to the right direction. Template method seems the one I need :)

Comment: Hi George,
I've looked into your MVC barebones framework, sounds awesome. Also, studying the Template Method.
I've up-voted your answer now. I wish I could accept it as well since you have addressed the second part. But unfortunately only one has to be accepted. I hope you'd understand.
I am very thankful to you for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is exactly what you needed. But you might like to try using the chaining mechanism:-

```
abstract class CommunicationService {
// child classes must implement this
abstract function send();
abstract function receive();

public function log($action) {
    echo 'Creating nice Log on = ' . $action;
    return $this;
}
```

}

```
class ServiceA extends CommunicationService {
public function send() {
    // Is it possible that the parent's logging functionality be invoked automatically by default?
    echo 'Send Message using Service A';
}
public function receive() {
    echo 'Receive Message using Service A';
}
```

}

```
$serviceA = new ServiceA();
$serviceA->log('send')->send(); // It should send message as well as create logs.
$serviceA->receive(); // It should just receive message and not log it.
```

Comment: Thanks @Khem.
I am aware of the chaining but what if someone forgets to call the log function in their implementation? They just call $serviceA->send(); 
Is there any way that we could force Child to call the $serviceA->log('send'); when they implement send() ?

Comment: @Waqas what if someone doesn't want to call the `log` function in their implementation?

Comment: @N.B.
The thing is Log is the requirement from the Parent. I am sorry I might not be able to explain well. But the logging is required by some other business rules, for example, parent wants to keep track of the activity. Let me know if it makes sense?

Comment: @Waqas I understand what you're after, but logically it doesn't make sense. If I want to send something, I call `send`. If I want to log the message, I call `log`. I can't see what business rule should force me to log, if I don't want to. However, there are multiple ways to achieve this enforcement and silent logging. Is that `send` function writing to a socket or is it just echoing some text?

Comment: @N.B. Thank you for your input. In this example it's just echoing. But in fact, the send method will send an SMS text. There will be different services who will be responsible to send SMS. I want the SMS to be logged centrally (regardless of service type). Also, an Event will be triggered as soon as the log is created. So, things are depended on the log. If a Child forgets to call log. The dependent functionality will break. 
I agree this might be a poor design. So, I am open for suggestions?